# Anyone know about Jasypt (Java encryption library)?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

From googling I found Jasypt, I'm wondering is it reliable?  Anyone know about it?

Answer (score 5):

I have come across it in my occupation and found it useful for verifying encryption algorithms from another source. I can't go into much detail of my verification processes but if you want to be able to encrypt data local to your PC then Jasypt is a great option. It abstracts a lot of crypto functionality and you can encrypt or decrypt data inside of 4 lines of code. However, if you want to encrypt traffic over a network then you may want to look into IPsec support. I also don't think you can configure the more granular settings in Jasypt like specifying a block or stream cipher type.